# Issue with Multithreading, saying it finished before the tasks haven't

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I've coded a void to handle multiple threads for selenium web browsing. The issue is that right now for example, if i input 4 tasks, and 2 threads. The program says it finished when it has finished 2 tasks.

Edit: Basically I want the program to wait for the tasks to complete And also I want that if one thread finishes but the other is running and there are tasks to do, it goes directly to start another task, and not waiting for the 2nd thread to finish.

Thanks and sorry for the code, made it fast to show it as a example of how it is.

```
    {
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Threads(4, 4);
        Console.WriteLine("Program has finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Random ran = new Random();
    static int loop;
    public static void Threads(int number, int threads)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (threads == 1)
            {
                generateDriver();
            }
            else if (threads > 1)
            {
            start:
                if (loop < threads)
                {
                    loop++;
                    Thread thread = new Thread(() => generateDriver());
                    thread.Start();

                }
                else 
                {
                    Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
                    goto start;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void test(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");
        int timer = ran.Next(100, 2000);
        Task.Delay(timer).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss") + "] - " + "Task done.");
        loop--;
        driver.Close();
    }

    public static void generateDriver()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.AddArguments("window-size=1024,768");
        options.AddArguments("--test-type");

        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
        test(driver);
    }
```

Comment: I added the code @LarsTech

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Thread` instead of `Task`? With tasks you could simply call `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: Also why are you using `goto` instead of a second `for` loop?

Comment: @UnholySheep If I have many more tasks I cannot use waitall I think? I guess I tried it before and it didnt work.

Comment: I tried many things like adding another for loop but resulted on other issue.

Comment: You specify which tasks to wait for as a parameter for `Task.WaitAll`, so I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @UnholySheep I dont want to wait for those tasks. I want if one task finishes and there are more tasks to be run, another one continues to go through.

Comment: That sounds different than what your question specifies. Your question says that you want to wait until all threads/tasks have finished. That would be achieved by starting all of them and then calling `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: As a side note, `Threads` is not a good name for a method. Methods should have verbs or verb phrases as names (like for example `StartThreads`). You could check the [official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-methods) if you want. Also `number` is not a good name for a parameter, because it is not very meaningful in this context (it could be meaningful for a method dealing with pure mathematics, like `IsPrime`).

Comment: Edited, I apologize for the confusion @UnholySheep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually keeping track of running threads, waiting for them to finish and reusing ones that are already finished is not trivial.
However the .NET runtime provides ready made solutions that you should prefer to handling it yourself.
The simplest way to achieve your desired result is to use a `Parallel.For` loop and set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, e.g.:

```
public static void Threads(int number, int threads)
{
    Parallel.For(0, number,
                 new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads },
                 _ => generateDriver());
}
```

If you really want to do it manually you will need to use arrays of `Thread` (or `Task`)  and keep iterating over them, checking whether they have finished and if they did replace them with a new thread. This requires quite a bit more code than the `Parallel.For` solution (and is unlikely to perform better)